# Unable to extract .exe (7zip self extracting archive) using SevenZipExtractor

Tags: c#, exe, 7zip

Lib used: https://github.com/adoconnection/SevenZipExtractor

```
       var file = @"C:\Users\PC\Desktop\SelfExtractFile.exe";
       var destination = @"C:\Users\PC\Desktop\";

       using ( ArchiveFile archiveFile = new ArchiveFile(file))
       {
         archiveFile.Extract(destination, true);
       }
```

I get: : 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
archive and entries are null.

The library says it supports .exe.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SevenZipExtractor](https://github.com/adoconnection/SevenZipExtractor) library doesn't support **self-extracting archive (SFX)**. It just supports extracting standard exe files.

But you can run **self-extracting archive** in a process in a silent mode:

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var file = @"c:\selfextracting.exe";
        var destination = @"C:\Users\PC\Desktop\";

        var output = ExtractSelfExtractingArchive(file, destination);

        Console.WriteLine(output);
    }

    private static string ExtractSelfExtractingArchive(string archiveFilePath, string destination)
    {
        try
        {
            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = archiveFilePath;
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = $" -o\"{destination}\" -y";
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

            process.Start();
            string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            process.WaitForExit();

            return output;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {

            return exception.Message;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I was using the process before but without the -y arg and ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden so I change it and it works great.